DB2 filter sql for condition



ID
ABBREV




1
A


1
B


2
B


2
B



When I am filter for ID = 1,
then I want in my result only the first line as result, A has priority on same id.
When I am filter for ID = 2,
then I want both results, line 3 and 4, because A was not listed.
Anything is wrong in my sql...
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE ID = 1
AND ABBREV  = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE ID = 1
AND ABBREV  = 'B'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(ABBREV) = 'A'


You can also try using CTE and  ROW_NUMBER()
    with main_1 (ID, ABBREV) as (values 
    (1, 'A')  
    ,(1, 'B')
    ,(2, 'B')
    ,(2, 'B')
    ), 
    main_2 AS (
    SELECT main_1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN1, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  ABBREV ORDER BY ABBREV DESC) AS RN2 FROM main_1
    ),
    main_3 AS (
    SELECT main_2.* FROM main_2 
    WHERE main_2.ABBREV = 'A' AND main_2.RN1 = 1 or main_2.RN2 >= 2
    )
 
    SELECT ID, ABBREV FROM main_3
    ORDER BY id

dbfiddle

ID|ABBREV|
--+------+
 1|A     |
 2|B     |
 2|B     |




Try using exists, but I'm not sure if I understand you
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE ID = 1
AND ABBREV = 'A'

UNION ALL

SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE ID = 1
AND ABBREV = 'B'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE_X
    WHERE ID = 1
    AND ABBREV = 'A'
)


